# Why I cannot restore offline database - keep getting error

Tags: sql-server, restore

I tried to restore database with another backup file (`.bak`).

Database has been set offline, but I keep getting errors:

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\.mdf'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 8, Line 3
>   File '' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\.ldf'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 8, Line 3
>   File '_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: did you take a look that the error message yourself ?

Comment: yes.but now I realize new problem. original database (source of backup file), can't be accessed. it said "restoring"..